# Advanced Regex - Capture Whole Group of Complex Statement inside Replace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a project, and I need to parse related data... the tools I work with is fully command based, and return all kind of stuff, so the regex come handy instead of guess that this line is that, and the other is this, ... so I need to parse this like:

> 1  QB 1283 /YR VC MC   MO22AUG IFNTHR 2240   2335   100 0 S

which depending on the condition may appear on many shapes, but, this will work hopefully:

`.*((/)?(?<Class>(\w{2}\s+)+)(\w{2}\d{2}\w{3})?\s+\w{6}).*`

There is just an issue, I need to capture only this part:
`YR VC MC` and there's no guarantee that there's always three of them... I tried parentheses grouping, as well as naming as you can see, I don't know how to capture a group in C#, though I think it use the Regex->Replace and then replace the whole data with the selected group (in hear 'Class' group), but it only match the last part,.. of inner parentheses, not the whole of it. for example in the above line it will returns "MC" not three of them, i also tried to replace `(\w{2}\s+)+)` with `(\w{2}\s+|\w{2}\s+\w{2}\s+|\w{2}\s+\w{2}\s+\w{2}\s+)` but it didn't worked either.

Any one can help me with this matter?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it un-greedy:

```
.*?((/)?(?<Class>(\w{2}\s+)+)(\w{2}\d{2}\w{3})?\s+\w{6}).*
  ^
```

Or remove both greedy dots from both ends. You don't need them:

```
/?(?<Class>(?:\w{2}\s+)+)(?:\w{2}\d{2}\w{3})?\s+\w{6}
```

Comment: can you also explain why and how it work that this happen?

Comment: An un-greedy (lazy) quantifier takes one step at a single advance. So in your case it goes ahead till stops before `/` mark step by step. If it is greedy (like how you wrote it) it consumes all characters at the very first place (up to end of line) then backtracks to check if next patterns are going to happen. In that case engine doesn't match `(/)?` since its optional and it can be ignored. So it ignores it as soon as possible and first `\w{2}\s+` occurence is the one that satisfies engine. @deadManN

Answer (score 3):

### Capture Groups

Let's back up a bit. First, we need to understand what [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) are. Everything put within parenthesis will be a capturing group. So, for instance, the regex `(\d)(\d)` with the string `89` will capture `8` in the first group and `9` in the second group. Let's say you make the second digit optional, so `(\d)(\d?)`. Now, if you try to match just `8`, the first group will be `8`, and the second group will just be an empty string. In this way, we can match all groups, even if some are 'missing'.

### Non-Capture Groups

Your regular expression seems to have a ton of unnecessary capture groups. If you don't need it, don't use parenthesis. For example, for `(/)?`, you can simply remove the parenthesis. What if you want to match the string "123" ten times? You'd probably do something like `(123){10}`. But hey, that's another unneeded capture group! You can create a non-capture group by using `(?:)` instead of `()`. This way, you won't be capturing whatever is within the parenthesis, but you'll be effectively using the parentheses to your convenience.

### Your Regex

Removing all unneccessary capture groups from your regex, we end up with:

```
.*/?(\w{2}\s+)+(?:\w{2}\d{2}\w{3})?\s+\w{6}.*.
```

Which includes the space within the capture group, so let's bring that out:

```
.*/?(\w{2})\s+(?:\w{2}\d{2}\w{3})?\s+\w{6}.*.
```

At this point, the capture group `(\w{2})` only matches the `MC` in your sample string, so let's do what you did and split it off into three different capture groups. Note that we can't do something like `(\w{2}){1,3}` (which will match `\w{2}` one to three times), because this still only has one single set of parenthesis, so it only has one single capture group. As such, we will need to expand our `(\w{2})\s+` to `(\w{2})\s+(\w{2})\s+(\w{2})\s+`. This regex will correctly capture your three strings.

### Regex in C#

In C#, we have this handy Regex class in System.Text.RegularExpressions. This is how you would use it:

```
string regex = @".*/?(\w{2})\s+(\w{2})\s+(\w{2})\s+(?:\w{2}\d{2}\w{3})?\s+\w{6}.*";
string sample = "1 QB 1283 /YR VC MC MO22AUG IFNTHR 2240 2335 100 0 S";
Match matches = Regex.Match (sample, regex);
string[] stringGroups = matches.Groups
    .Cast<Group> ()
    .Select (el => el.Value)
    .ToArray ();
```

Here, stringGroups will be a string array with all the capture groups. stringGroups[0] will be the entire match (so in this case, `1 QB 1283 /YR VC MC MO22AUG IFNTHR 2240 2335 100 0 S`), stringGroups[1] will be the first capture group (`YR` in this case), stringGroups[2] the second, and stringGroups[3] the third.

PS: I highly recommend [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) for testing this type of stuff.